# jQuery - click function does not work on dynamically generated button with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have this tag on my HTML file

```
<tbody id="list" >
```

in which I integrated some other tags to generate multiple buttons using jquery :

```
var html = '';
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
    { html += '<tr>';
      html += '<td>';
      html +='<a class="btn btn-primary btn-delete-item" id="' +i+'" >Remove</a>';
      html += '</td>';
      html += '</tr>';

    }
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = html;
});
```

and then I wanted to add a functionnality to every generated button so I wrote this:

```
$("#list ").click(function(id) {
 console.log(id); // to check if the id parameter is passed to the function
 // rest of the function
}
```

My problem is that console.log's output is "undefined", so how can I pass the id to the function parameter?

Comment: Why mix JS and jQuery? Just use jQuery since you anyway have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#list").on("click", ".btn", function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

or

```
$("#list").delegate(".btn", "click", function(e) {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

read Delegates on Jquery
Hope this helps

Comment: dude!! $(this).id will not work. u have to use $(this).attr('id') or this.id

Comment: you are welcome. if this helps you please mark it as answer and give vote for that. :)

Comment: Use may also use `this.id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the on function for event delegation:

```
$('#list').on('click','.btn-delete-item',function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: the problem is that $('.btn-delete-item') is invisible to the jquery functions... if i don't write  $("#list ").click(function() , the function dosn't even launch

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".btn-primary").on('click',function(id) {
 console.log($(this).attr('id')); // to check if the id parameter is passed to the function
 // rest of the function
});
```

This will work!!

check this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jisiwuyari/1/edit?html,js,console,output) for working code!!

Comment: nope, this only shows the id of the list, not the button

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: u need click function for the dynamic generated button?

Comment: ok ok.. I understood ur problem, Since u generated the markup dynamically , u have to use .on function or .live(jquery <= 1.7)

Answer (score 0):

The argument to your click event handler is the event object. The scope within the handler will be the sender so:

```
$("#list").click(function(event) 
{
  var elem = $(this);
  // you can inspect any property of the element here
  console.log(elem.attr('id'));
}
```

You might also want to look into [event delegation using jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).